# How to set templates for application.properties file in Eclipse?

Tags: spring, eclipse, application.properties

I could easily set the template for pom.xml and regular java, but I could not figure out how to set a template (snippets) for the application.properties (spring) file?

Cntl + Space shows snippets I just have no idea where inside Eclipse I could add more
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFD1R.png)

Comment: Do you already have a special editor installed that provides the templates you *are* seeing proposed? Does it not have a page for adding more? If not, the Snippets View might be an alternative you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link which can help you set Template for Application.properties file
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#templating-properties